# Can I put imports into a separate file?

Tags: java, android, import, include

I am new to java.

I am writing an android app and there are many import directives at the beginning of my main.java file.

Is there a way to put all import directives into a separate file and somehow just include it in the main.java file?

Comment: No. You need the imports where you use the classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, that's not possible. Imports must always be in the file in which they are used.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot put imports in a separate file, it is not generally a problem when using an IDE.
Anyway, you can try to reduce the number imports by using a star character to import all classes of a package, like:

```
import java.io.*;
```

Comment: The * notation for imports has always been frowned upon in every place I have worked and in fact, SonarQube even checks for that. Just use an IDE to expand that to the classes you are actually using.